If $(X,T)$ is a compact Haussdorff space and X is countable, then the set $\{x:\{x\} \in T\} $ is dense in $(X,T)$
If $(X,T)$ is a compact Haussdorff space and X is countable, then the set $\{x:\{x\} \in T\} $ is dense in $(X,T)$ ?
Apologize if it is elementary. but here goes what I`ve tried so far
Since that it is compact it means that $X$ is the union of finitely many open sets in $T$, and since $X$ is countable it means that each of those open sets is countable.
I see that if I manage to prove that each singleton is contained in the topology, then we are done and it could be proven if the finite intersection of elements of $T$ by the definition of topology, is any singleton, but I am having trouble in figuring it out solely from the definitions of compactness, Hausdorffness and countability. Can someone give me a hint of how to conclude it?
Thanks in advance

Sorry. I meant the singleton contained in the topology. Fixed it now.

Your attempt to prove that each singleton is open cannot work: $X={0}\cup{1/n,n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is compact, Haussdorf and countable. However, the point $0$ is not open (although any other point is).

So how should I proceed?

You can show this using the Baire Category Theorem. Let $Y$ be the set of all $x$ such that $\{x\}$ is not open (AKA "such that $x$ is non-isolated"). This is the complement of the set you're interested in. For each $x \in Y$, the set $X \setminus \{x\}$ is not closed, so its closure is $X$ - so it is a dense open set. Hence, $\bigcap_{x \in Y} X \setminus \{x\}$ is a dense subset of $X$, by BCT. But this set is just $X \setminus Y$, so we are done.

Thank you. I see now that Haussdorf and compact implies Baire space.

@VictorHugo, yes that's right. Generally if you see "countable, compact, Hausdorff" or "countable, complete metric" in one place, this should set off your "BCT alarm bells"!

First, it is enough to show that any such $X$ contains at least one isolated point $x$, i.e., $\{x\}\in T$. This is because any non-empty open set $U$ of  $X$ contains a non-empty open set $V$ whose closure is contained in $U$ and since this closure is also a compact countable Hausdorff space, it containes an open singleton, which must be contained in $V$ and thus is open in $X$ as well. Thus, any non-empty open set $U$
contains an isolated point, hence isolated points are dense.
It remains to show that $X$ contains an isolated point.
Suppose that $X$ does not contain an isolated point, then one can embed $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ into $X$, but then $X$ would not be countable.
How can one embed  $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ into $X$?
Recursively define non-empty open sets $U_a$ for $a\in \{0,1\}^{0,...,n-1}$ such that their closures are pairwise disjoint, there diameters are less then $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\overline{U_a}\subseteq U_b$ if $a$ extends $b$ (i.e., $a\in \{0,1\}^{0,...,n-1}$, $b\in \{0,1\}^{0,...,m-1}$, $m<n$ and $b_k=a_k$ for all $k<m$). How can one do this? At each step just choose two distinct points $x,y\in U_a$ (we can do this because $U_a$ is not a singleton by assumption) and choose neighbourhoods of $x,y$ fullfilling the criteria. Then for each  $x\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the set $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{n}}U_{x|n}$ contains exactly one point using compactness and for distinct $x,y \in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we get distinct points, thus $X$ is not countable.
